# Print all files in folder VBA code not working

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm trying to print all files inside a folder with this code but something is not working correctly...

```
Sub Bulk_Print_From_Folder()

Dim k       As Variant
Dim n       As Variant
Dim oFile   As Object
Dim oFiles  As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim Path    As Variant
Dim vItem   As Object

    Path = "C:\Testing Folder"

    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set oFolder = .Namespace(Path)
        If oFolder Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "The Folder :" & vbLf & """" & Path & """ was Not Found.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    Set oFiles = oFolder.Items
        oFiles.Filter 64, "*.pdf;*.jpg;*.png;*.txt"

        For n = 0 To oFiles.Count - 1
            Set oFile = oFiles.Item(n)
            For k = 0 To oFile.Verbs.Count - 1
                Set vItem = oFile.Verbs.Item(k)
                If Not vItem Is Nothing Then
                    If Replace(vItem, "&", "") = "Print" Then vItem.DoIt
                End If
            Next k
        Next n

     End Sub
```

**Extra Info:**

»» I have macros enabled and default printer defined... The printer is working correctly.

»» I noticed that I don't see the printer icon in Taskbar after hit the button to execute this code. And if it maters, I'm using Office 2007 Ultimate.

»» I know that it finds the folder. I tested by altering the folder name on the code and I got the message

```
MsgBox "The Folder :" & vbLf & """" & Path & """ was Not Found.", vbCritical
```

**This are my project references:**

[image]

A'm I missing something?

Comment: Is `Path` a VBA reserved name?

Comment: How can I know that and how could this interfere with the action of the code?

Comment: I think `Path` is being recognized as `Application.Path`. Try using a different variable name, such as `MyPath,ThisPath` or something else

Comment: It works for me. Can you put a breakpoint in `If Replace(vItem, "&", "") = "Print" Then vItem.DoIt` and see if the code stops there?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I've replaced the `Path` with `ThisPath` and nothing happens

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes. It stop's there.

Comment: And does it execute the line `vItem.DoIt`? Also check one thing fo rme. Manually go to that folder and right click on the image Do you see print in the context menu?

Comment: @SiddharthRout No. Can you compare your project references with my (picture above)?

Comment: See the 2nd part of my comment above... I just updated it...

Comment: @SiddharthRout No. I don't see "print" in the context menu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191449/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-alex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

The problem is with the default program set for opening the image file. If you right click on the image file, you will not see the `Print` option. To sort this issue, open `Control panel` and go to `Default Apps`. Change the default app of `Photo Viewer` to say `Paint`. Close `Default Apps`

Now right click on the image file and you will see the `Print` option. If you do see `Print`, then your code will now run as `vItem` will have `&Print`

If you have a mix of files in that folder and you do not see a `Print` option for any particular extention then do what I suggested above. Change the default app till you see the `Print` in the context menu.

Depending on OS, you may see `&Print` or `&Print out` or something in a regional language. You can test that by using this code

```
For n = 0 To oFiles.Count - 1
    Set oFile = oFiles.Item(n)
    For k = 0 To oFile.Verbs.Count - 1
        Set vItem = oFile.Verbs.Item(k)
        If Not vItem Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print vItem
        End If
    Next k
Next n
```

So you may want to change the code

```
If Replace(vItem, "&", "") = "Print" Then
```

to

```
If InStr(1, vItem, "&Print") Then
```

or to

```
InStr(1, vItem, "imprimir", vbTextCompare) '<~~ See Chat below quesiton
```

Comment: Thank you very much! **Just one more thing:** Is there any way to print all files in sub-folders?